# PostgreSQL - Parse Complex XML and load to tables

Tags: postgresql, xpath, xmltable

Need a little bit of help here. I have a scenario where I want to parse an XML and insert data into a postgreSQL table. I need to parse around 100,000 XMLs an example of one of these XML is given below. However, the issue is with the unnest() function of XPATH, the query takes forever to load(20 mins approximately).  I have tried XMLTABLE as well however the query requires multiple CTEs or temporary tables build upon XMLTABLE to handle nested nodes which is again slow. **Is there a way to optimize?** Query used is provided below - 
**SQL Query**

```
INSERT INTO stateful_cc_ingest.job_details  (ronumber, linlinecode, linlinecode_idx, hostitemid, lincause, lincause_idx, linstorytext, linstorytext_idx, linservicerequest, linservicerequest_idx, linaddonflag, linaddonflag_idx, store_id, closeddate) (
              SELECT
                  (xpath('(//dns:RONumber/text())[1]'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))[1]::text::varchar AS ronumber,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linLineCode/dns:V/text()[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text AS linlinecode,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linLineCode/dns:V/@Idx[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text::integer AS linlinecode_idx,
                  (xpath('(//dns:HostItemID/text())[1]'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))[1]::text AS hostitemid,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linCause/dns:V/text()[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text AS lincause,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linCause/dns:V/@Idx[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text::integer AS lincause_idx,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linStoryText/dns:V/text()[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text AS linstorytext,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linStoryText/dns:V/@Idx[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text::integer AS linstorytext_idx,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linServiceRequest/dns:V/text()[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text AS linservicerequest,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linServiceRequest/dns:V/@Idx[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text::integer AS linservicerequest_idx,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linAddOnFlag/dns:V/text()[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text AS linaddonflag,
                  unnest(xpath('(//dns:linAddOnFlag/dns:V/@Idx[1])'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))::text::integer AS linaddonflag_idx,
                  data_detail.store_id,
                  (xpath('(//dns:ClosedDate/text())[1]'::text, data_detail.ro_data_xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['dns'::text, 'http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history'::text]]))[1]::text::date AS closeddate
              FROM
                  stateful_cdk_source_raw.cdk_data_detail data_detail
              CROSS JOIN fdw_stateful_service_configuration.configuration_value conf
          WHERE
              data_detail.store_id = in_store_id
              AND closed_date IS NOT NULL
              AND closed_date > conf.value::date
              AND conf.short_key = 'CLD'
              AND conf.party_id = in_store_id
              AND data_detail.statuscode IS NOT NULL
              AND data_detail.statusdesc IS NOT NULL)
      ON CONFLICT (store_id,
          ronumber,
          closeddate,
          linlinecode)
          DO NOTHING;
      END;
      $function$
```

**Sample XML**

```
<service-repair-order-history
    xmlns="http://www.dmotorworks.com/service-repair-order-history">
    <prtQtyBackordered>
        <V Idx="1">0</V>
        <V Idx="2">0</V>
    </prtQtyBackordered>
    <prtQtyFilled>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">8</V>
    </prtQtyFilled>
    <prtQtyOnHand>
        <V Idx="1">105</V>
        <V Idx="2">-818</V>
    </prtQtyOnHand>
    <punMultivalueCount>1</punMultivalueCount>
    <punTechNo>
        <V Idx="1">1809</V>
    </punTechNo>
    <punWorkDate>
        <V Idx="1">2021-01-22</V>
    </punWorkDate>
    <punTimeOn>
        <V Idx="1">15:18:00</V>
    </punTimeOn>
    <punTimeOff>
        <V Idx="1">16:06:00</V>
    </punTimeOff>
    <punDuration>
        <V Idx="1">0.80</V>
    </punDuration>
    <punLineCode>
        <V Idx="1">C B A</V>
    </punLineCode>
    <punWorkType>
        <V Idx="1">W</V>
    </punWorkType>
    <BlockAutoMsg/>
    <BookedTime>16:09:14</BookedTime>
    <dedActualAmount/>
    <dedLaborAmount/>
    <dedLaborType/>
    <dedLineCodes/>
    <dedMaximumAmount/>
    <dedMultivalueCount>0</dedMultivalueCount>
    <dedPartsAmount/>
    <dedSequenceNo/>
    <disAppliedBy/>
    <disClassOrType/>
    <disDesc/>
    <disDiscountID/>
    <disLaborDiscount/>
    <disLevel/>
    <disLineCode/>
    <disLopSeqNo/>
    <disManagerOverride/>
    <disMultivalueCount>0</disMultivalueCount>
    <disOriginalDiscount/>
    <disOverrideAmount/>
    <disOverrideGPAmount/>
    <disOverrideGPPercent/>
    <disOverridePercent/>
    <disOverrideTarget/>
    <disPartsDiscount/>
    <disSequenceNo/>
    <disTotalDiscount/>
    <EmailAddress>
        <V mailto:idx="1">dnh@dlr.com</V>
    </EmailAddress>
    <EmailDesc>
        <V Idx="1">HOME</V>
    </EmailDesc>
    <EmailMultivalueCount>1</EmailMultivalueCount>
    <feeLOPorPartFlag/>
    <feeLOPorPartSeqNo/>
    <feeMcdPercentage/>
    <feeMultivalueCount>0</feeMultivalueCount>
    <feeSale/>
    <feeSequenceNo/>
    <feeType/>
    <HasCustPayFlag>N</HasCustPayFlag>
    <HasIntPayFlag>Y</HasIntPayFlag>
    <HasWarrPayFlag>Y</HasWarrPayFlag>
    <hrsFlagHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </hrsFlagHours>
    <hrsMcdPercentage>
        <V Idx="1">100</V>
        <V Idx="2">100</V>
        <V Idx="3">100</V>
    </hrsMcdPercentage>
    <hrsMultivalueCount>3</hrsMultivalueCount>
    <hrsSequenceNo>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">2</V>
        <V Idx="3">3</V>
    </hrsSequenceNo>
    <hrsTimeCardHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </hrsTimeCardHours>
    <lbrActualHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.80</V>
    </lbrActualHours>
    <lbrComebackFlag>
        <V Idx="1">N</V>
        <V Idx="2">N</V>
        <V Idx="3">N</V>
    </lbrComebackFlag>
    <lbrComebackRO/>
    <lbrComebackSA/>
    <lbrComebackTech/>
    <lbrFlagHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </lbrFlagHours>
    <lbrForcedShopCharge/>
    <lbrLineCode>
        <V Idx="1">A</V>
        <V Idx="2">B</V>
        <V Idx="3">C</V>
    </lbrLineCode>
    <lbrMultivalueCount>3</lbrMultivalueCount>
    <lbrOperationType/>
    <lbrOtherHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </lbrOtherHours>
    <lbrSoldHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.80</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </lbrSoldHours>
    <LicenseNumber>NRP8569</LicenseNumber>
    <linActualWork>
        <V Idx="1">3</V>
        <V Idx="2">3</V>
        <V Idx="3">1</V>
    </linActualWork>
    <linAddOnFlag>
        <V Idx="1">N</V>
        <V Idx="2">N</V>
        <V Idx="3">N</V>
    </linAddOnFlag>
    <linBookerNo>
        <V Idx="1">1492</V>
        <V Idx="2">1492</V>
        <V Idx="3">1492</V>
    </linBookerNo>
    <linMultivalueCount>3</linMultivalueCount>
    <linStorySequenceNo>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
    </linStorySequenceNo>
    <linStoryText>
        <V Idx="1">8673    LOF AND TIRE ROTATION COMPLETE, LEARNED TIRE POSITIONS AND SET TO 42 PSI</V>
    </linStoryText>
    <LotLocation/>
    <mlsCost/>
    <mlsLaborType/>
    <mlsLineCode/>
    <mlsMcdPercentage/>
    <mlsMultivalueCount>0</mlsMultivalueCount>
    <mlsOpCode/>
    <mlsOpCodeDesc/>
    <mlsSale/>
    <mlsSequenceNo/>
    <ModelDesc>SILVERADO 1500</ModelDesc>
    <OpenTime>15:13:51</OpenTime>
    <payCPTotal/>
    <payMultivalueCount>1</payMultivalueCount>
    <payPaymentAmount>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
    </payPaymentAmount>
    <payPaymentCode>
        <V Idx="1">CASH</V>
    </payPaymentCode>
    <payPaymentsMade/>
    <PhoneDesc>
        <V Idx="1">HomePhone</V>
        <V Idx="2">MainPhone</V>
    </PhoneDesc>
    <PhoneExt/>
    <PhoneMultivalueCount>2</PhoneMultivalueCount>
    <PhoneNumber>
        <V Idx="1">9726394152</V>
        <V Idx="2">9726394152</V>
    </PhoneNumber>
    <prtExtendedCost>
        <V Idx="1">3.56</V>
        <V Idx="2">26.96</V>
    </prtExtendedCost>
    <prtExtendedSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.04</V>
        <V Idx="2">34.96</V>
    </prtExtendedSale>
    <prtLaborSequenceNo>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">1</V>
    </prtLaborSequenceNo>
    <prtLineCode>
        <V Idx="1">A</V>
        <V Idx="2">A</V>
    </prtLineCode>
    <prtMultivalueCount>2</prtMultivalueCount>
    <prtSequenceNo>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">2</V>
    </prtSequenceNo>
    <punAlteredFlag>
        <V Idx="1">N</V>
    </punAlteredFlag>
    <rapMultivalueCount>0</rapMultivalueCount>
    <StatusCode>C98</StatusCode>
    <StatusDesc>CLOSED</StatusDesc>
    <totActualHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.80</V>
    </totActualHours>
    <totCoreCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totCoreCost>
    <totCoreSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totCoreSale>
    <totDiscount>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totDiscount>
    <totFlagHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totFlagHours>
    <totForcedShopCharge>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totForcedShopCharge>
    <totLaborCount>
        <V Idx="1">0</V>
        <V Idx="2">1</V>
        <V Idx="3">2</V>
    </totLaborCount>
    <totLaborDiscount>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLaborDiscount>
    <totLaborSalePostDed>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">15.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLaborSalePostDed>
    <totLubeCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLubeCost>
    <totLubeCount>
        <V Idx="1">0</V>
        <V Idx="2">0</V>
        <V Idx="3">0</V>
    </totLubeCount>
    <totMiscCount>
        <V Idx="1">0</V>
        <V Idx="2">0</V>
        <V Idx="3">0</V>
    </totMiscCount>
    <totMultivalueCount>3</totMultivalueCount>
    <totOtherHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totOtherHours>
    <totPartsCount>
        <V Idx="1">0</V>
        <V Idx="2">9</V>
        <V Idx="3">0</V>
    </totPartsCount>
    <totPartsDiscount>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totPartsDiscount>
    <totPartsSalePostDed>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">35.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totPartsSalePostDed>
    <totPayType>
        <V Idx="1">C</V>
        <V Idx="2">W</V>
        <V Idx="3">I</V>
    </totPayType>
    <totRoCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">47.32</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totRoCost>
    <totRoSalePostDed>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">50.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totRoSalePostDed>
    <totRoTax>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totRoTax>
    <totShopChargeCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totShopChargeCost>
    <totSubletCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totSubletCost>
    <totSubletCount>
        <V Idx="1">0</V>
        <V Idx="2">0</V>
        <V Idx="3">0</V>
    </totSubletCount>
    <totTimeCardHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totTimeCardHours>
    <warAuthorizationCode/>
    <warClaimType/>
    <warConditionCode/>
    <warFailedPartNo/>
    <warFailedPartsCount/>
    <warLaborSequenceNo/>
    <warLineCode/>
    <warMultivalueCount>0</warMultivalueCount>
    <Zip>23661-2716</Zip>
    <AddOnFlag>N</AddOnFlag>
    <Address>107 HOLLYWOOD AVE</Address>
    <ApptDate/>
    <ApptFlag>N</ApptFlag>
    <ApptTime/>
    <BookedDate>2021-01-22</BookedDate>
    <BookerNo>1492</BookerNo>
    <Cashier>phillip</Cashier>
    <CityStateZip>HAMPTON, VA 23661</CityStateZip>
    <ClosedDate>2021-01-22</ClosedDate>
    <ComebackFlag>N</ComebackFlag>
    <Comments/>
    <ContactEmailAddress/>
    <ContactPhoneNumber/>
    <CustNo>LG358915</CustNo>
    <DeliveryDate>2020-07-08</DeliveryDate>
    <ErrorLevel/>
    <ErrorMessage/>
    <EstComplDate>2021-01-22</EstComplDate>
    <EstComplTime>16:24:00</EstComplTime>
    <HostItemID>LG358915*851403</HostItemID>
    <LastServiceDate/>
    <Make>CHEV</Make>
    <MakeDesc>CHEVROLET</MakeDesc>
    <Mileage>8673</Mileage>
    <MileageLastVisit>8673</MileageLastVisit>
    <MileageOut>8673</MileageOut>
    <Model>SILV15</Model>
    <Name1>BECK,MATTHEW</Name1>
    <Name2/>
    <OpenDate>2021-01-22</OpenDate>
    <OrigPromisedDate>2021-01-22</OrigPromisedDate>
    <OrigPromisedTime/>
    <OrigWaiterFlag>Y</OrigWaiterFlag>
    <PostedDate>2021-01-22</PostedDate>
    <PriorityValue>5686</PriorityValue>
    <PromisedDate>2021-01-22</PromisedDate>
    <PromisedTime>17:00:00</PromisedTime>
    <PurchaseOrderNo/>
    <RONumber>851403</RONumber>
    <Remarks/>
    <RentalFlag>N</RentalFlag>
    <ServiceAdvisor>1492</ServiceAdvisor>
    <SoldByDealerFlag>Y</SoldByDealerFlag>
    <SpecialCustFlag>N</SpecialCustFlag>
    <TagNo>TNPR8569</TagNo>
    <VIN>3GCPYFED9LG358915</VIN>
    <VehID>LG358915</VehID>
    <VehicleColor/>
    <VoidedDate/>
    <WaiterFlag>Y</WaiterFlag>
    <Year>2020</Year>
    <disDebitAccountNo/>
    <disDebitControlNo/>
    <disDebitTargetCo/>
    <disUserID/>
    <feeCost/>
    <feeFeeID/>
    <feeLaborType/>
    <feeLineCode/>
    <feeOpCode/>
    <feeOpCodeDesc/>
    <hrsActualHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.80</V>
    </hrsActualHours>
    <hrsCost>
        <V Idx="1">16.80</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </hrsCost>
    <hrsHourType>
        <V Idx="1">ST</V>
        <V Idx="2">ST</V>
        <V Idx="3">ST</V>
    </hrsHourType>
    <hrsLaborType>
        <V Idx="1">WC06</V>
        <V Idx="2">ICPA</V>
        <V Idx="3">ICPA</V>
    </hrsLaborType>
    <hrsLineCode>
        <V Idx="1">A</V>
        <V Idx="2">B</V>
        <V Idx="3">C</V>
    </hrsLineCode>
    <hrsOtherHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </hrsOtherHours>
    <hrsPercentage>
        <V Idx="1">100.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">100.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">100.00</V>
    </hrsPercentage>
    <hrsSale>
        <V Idx="1">15.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </hrsSale>
    <hrsSoldHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.80</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </hrsSoldHours>
    <hrsTechNo>
        <V Idx="1">1809</V>
        <V Idx="2">1809</V>
        <V Idx="3">1809</V>
    </hrsTechNo>
    <lbrCost>
        <V Idx="1">16.80</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </lbrCost>
    <lbrLaborType>
        <V Idx="1">WC06</V>
        <V Idx="2">ICPA</V>
        <V Idx="3">ICPA</V>
    </lbrLaborType>
    <lbrMcdPercentage>
        <V Idx="1">100</V>
        <V Idx="2">100</V>
        <V Idx="3">100</V>
    </lbrMcdPercentage>
    <lbrOpCode>
        <V Idx="1">0600723</V>
        <V Idx="2">MPI</V>
        <V Idx="3">CSI</V>
    </lbrOpCode>
    <lbrOpCodeDesc>
        <V Idx="1">CHEVROLET 2YEAR SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE</V>
        <V Idx="2">Multi Point Vehicle Inspection</V>
        <V Idx="3">You may receive a Survey via email from Chevrolet in regard to your visit , we appreciate your feedback and thank you for choosing Hampton Chevrolet Thank you</V>
    </lbrOpCodeDesc>
    <lbrSale>
        <V Idx="1">15.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </lbrSale>
    <lbrSequenceNo>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">2</V>
        <V Idx="3">3</V>
    </lbrSequenceNo>
    <lbrTechNo>
        <V Idx="1">1809</V>
        <V Idx="2">1809</V>
        <V Idx="3">1809</V>
    </lbrTechNo>
    <lbrTimeCardHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </lbrTimeCardHours>
    <linCampaignCode/>
    <linCause>
        <V Idx="1">FACTORY MAINT</V>
    </linCause>
    <linComebackFlag>
        <V Idx="1">N</V>
        <V Idx="2">N</V>
        <V Idx="3">N</V>
    </linComebackFlag>
    <linComplaintCode>
        <V Idx="1">0600723</V>
        <V Idx="2">MPI</V>
        <V Idx="3">CSI</V>
    </linComplaintCode>
    <linDispatchCode>
        <V Idx="1">CS450</V>
        <V Idx="2">CS450</V>
        <V Idx="3">CS450</V>
    </linDispatchCode>
    <linEstDuration>
        <V Idx="1">0.3</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.3</V>
        <V Idx="3">2.0</V>
    </linEstDuration>
    <linLineCode>
        <V Idx="1">A</V>
        <V Idx="2">B</V>
        <V Idx="3">C</V>
    </linLineCode>
    <linServiceRequest>
        <V Idx="1">CHEVROLET 2YEAR SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE</V>
        <V Idx="2">Multi Point Vehicle Inspection</V>
        <V Idx="3">You may receive a Survey via email from Chevrolet in regard to your visit , we appreciate your feedback and thank you for choosing Hampton Chevrolet Thank you</V>
    </linServiceRequest>
    <linStatusCode/>
    <linStatusDesc/>
    <linStoryEmployeeNo>
        <V Idx="1">1809</V>
    </linStoryEmployeeNo>
    <mlsType/>
    <payInsuranceFlag>
        <V Idx="1">N</V>
    </payInsuranceFlag>
    <prtBin1>
        <V Idx="1">A1</V>
        <V Idx="2">TANK</V>
    </prtBin1>
    <prtClass>
        <V Idx="1">1836</V>
        <V Idx="2">8800</V>
    </prtClass>
    <prtComp>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
    </prtComp>
    <prtCompLineCode/>
    <prtCoreCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
    </prtCoreCost>
    <prtCoreSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
    </prtCoreSale>
    <prtCost>
        <V Idx="1">3.56</V>
        <V Idx="2">3.37</V>
    </prtCost>
    <prtDesc>
        <V Idx="1">(S)FILTER</V>
        <V Idx="2">OIL</V>
    </prtDesc>
    <prtEmployeeNo>
        <V Idx="1">170061</V>
        <V Idx="2">170061</V>
    </prtEmployeeNo>
    <prtLaborType>
        <V Idx="1">WC06</V>
        <V Idx="2">WC06</V>
    </prtLaborType>
    <prtList>
        <V Idx="1">7.12</V>
        <V Idx="2">6.84</V>
    </prtList>
    <prtMcdPercentage>
        <V Idx="1">100</V>
        <V Idx="2">100</V>
    </prtMcdPercentage>
    <prtOutsideSalesmanNo/>
    <prtPartNo>
        <V Idx="1">19419227</V>
        <V Idx="2">88865700</V>
    </prtPartNo>
    <prtQtyOrdered>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">8</V>
    </prtQtyOrdered>
    <prtQtySold>
        <V Idx="1">1</V>
        <V Idx="2">8</V>
    </prtQtySold>
    <prtSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.04</V>
        <V Idx="2">4.37</V>
    </prtSale>
    <prtSource>
        <V Idx="1">191</V>
        <V Idx="2">184</V>
    </prtSource>
    <prtSpecialStatus/>
    <prtUnitServiceCharge>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
    </prtUnitServiceCharge>
    <rapApptID/>
    <totLaborCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">16.80</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLaborCost>
    <totLaborSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">15.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLaborSale>
    <totLocalTax>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLocalTax>
    <totLubeSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totLubeSale>
    <totMiscCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totMiscCost>
    <totMiscSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totMiscSale>
    <totPartsCost>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">30.52</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totPartsCost>
    <totPartsSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">35.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totPartsSale>
    <totShopChargeSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totShopChargeSale>
    <totSoldHours>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.80</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totSoldHours>
    <totStateTax>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totStateTax>
    <totSubletSale>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totSubletSale>
    <totSupp2Tax>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totSupp2Tax>
    <totSupp3Tax>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totSupp3Tax>
    <totSupp4Tax>
        <V Idx="1">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="2">0.00</V>
        <V Idx="3">0.00</V>
    </totSupp4Tax>
    <warFailureCode/>
</service-repair-order-history>
```

**Expected Output**
[image: | left | center | right | left | center | right |left | center | right |:---- |:------:| -----:|:---- |:------:| -----:| | One | Two | Three |One | Two | Three |]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the expected result  of the SELECT based on your sample XMLt. Typically XMLTABLE is more flexible and easier to use than xpath()

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
 I am ok with using XMLTABLE as well but what concerns me with both these methods is the time taken to parse when I have 100000 XMLs like the one in my sample all at one go.

Comment: You can ignore the cross join in the query. It is just used to append to the table when we load data on a daily basis.